# Having issues with navigation view (SwiftUI, iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Code below:

```
NavigationView{
            ZStack{
                Color("SmokyBlack").ignoresSafeArea()
                VStack{
                    //ModularContent(titleName: titleName, subtitleText: subtitleText, imageName: imageName)
                        
                    NavigationLink(destination: SecondOnboardingView()){
                        OnboardingButton(buttonText: btnName, updateOnboarding: false)
                    }
                }
            }// parent vstack
            .preferredColorScheme(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.dark/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        } //nav view ends
```

My Issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLAkA.jpg

The button is clearly being pressed but nothing is happening

edit: code for the button. I have tried changing this button to plain text but it still doesn't work.

```
struct OnboardingButton: View {
    var buttonText: String
    var updateOnboarding: Bool
    
    @AppStorage("onboardingCheck") var onboardingCheck: Bool?
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {onboardingCheck=updateOnboarding},
            label: {
                ZStack{
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 60, alignment: .center)
                    Text(buttonText)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .font(.system(size: 20))
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                }
            })
            
    }
}
```

Comment: `NavigationLink` is basically a button, so here you likely are triggering the button inside `OnboardingButton`. Fix by changing from `Button` to `Text` in `OnboardingButton` for example.

Comment: You should post the code for OnboardingButton. If it is an actual button then it’s action maybe overriding the navigation link’s action. Have you tried using Text instead of your custom button?

Comment: I have, it does the same thing as posted above

Comment: Edited the post to add the code for the button

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have figured out why.

`Button(action: {onboardingCheck=updateOnboarding},`
from OnboardingButton seems to only accept true as an answer to continue . To work around this, I simply made a different file that does not use Button() but instead the following:

```
struct OnboardingButtonTwo: View {
    var buttonText: String
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .frame(width: 300, height: 60, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            Text(buttonText)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .font(.system(size: 20))
                .fontWeight(.semibold)
        }
        .padding(.bottom, 10)
    }
}
```